# Why there are different result on MT4 and MT5 after conversion from MQL4 to MQL5?

Tags: mql4, metatrader4, mql5, metatrader5

Here are the two results:

MT4:
[image: MT4 result image]

MT5:
[image: MT5 result image]

See the graphs. They are all opposite.
Here is the code:
[Problem_Mt4_To_MT5.mq4](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1k9YBOx7BqnN8-2-XW_JjvxuQ8zOn0NBL/view?usp=sharing)

The code works in MQL5 and MQL4 both.
Please let me know why there is a wide difference in both the graphs.
The MT4Orders.mqh is available here: https://www.mql5.com/ru/code/download/16006/mt4orders.mqh

Comment: are you sure the feed is the same? is it all ticks simulation? To make sure there's no problem with the code, put down all the ticks from mt4 (by using a simple EA and running all ticks) then import into MT5. I didnt see any difference with my ea if using same feeds, so that's not MT4Orders lib problem

Comment: I have checked the ticks from the MT4 and MT5. They are same. They even start from the same. Don't know why is this happening.

Comment: I am not quite sure what you mean by 'even start from the same'. Same feed means each and every bid and ask from one feed are equal to them in another feed. If some feed has more ticks - they are not equal. Importing MT4 ticks into MT5 (or tickdatasuite ticks to mt4 and mt5) is the first step. When you are sure that does not help - need to isolate wrong deals and debug

Comment: I do not understand what difference does it will make if I have different ticks? What is the reason for getting such a weird result as the broker is same: ICMarket?

Comment: even if broker is the same, ticks might (and 99% will) be different due to different reasons like different feed, MT5 server is faster, etc. Quite often the candles have differences too, even though not significant. Different ticks - different behaviour of the robot.

Comment: But why do different ticks have different behavior? Why the same broker on two different platform would give different ticks? I do not understand this. Can you help me with that?

Comment: is it a programming question? ask your broker why they have different feed on different platforms. Regarding your first question - it seems natural that different ticks lead to different trade actions and behaviour, isnt it? if not, you must have same result if running the ea on different pairs...